# Where was William imprisoned between 1202 and 1400?

Tags: underworld

From *Underworld: Evolution*, William, the first werewolf, was captured in the year 1202. Selene was born a couple decades before the year 1400 and was turned sometime around 1400. Her father built the cell for William when Selene was a young child, so there are nearly 200 years between the time of William’s capture and the construction of his prison.

Where was William kept during this time? Do the novelizations of the films say anything about this? The [Underworld Wiki](http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/William%27s_Prison) acknowledges this 200-year period but does not explain it.

He could have been kept in the vampires’ castle along with the rest of the werewolves, but he’s an especially powerful werewolf so they may have confined him somewhere more secure.